# How to avoid adding a fragment to the backstack if it already exists using Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using navigation component so I'm not using a FragmentManager. Let's say I have fragments A, B.

If user navigates A -> B -> A -> B and then presses the back button I want the backstack to just be A instead of A -> B -> A. In other words don't add a Fragment if it already exists in the backstack. Is this possible without using FragmentManager?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to use [`setPopUpTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder.html#setPopUpTo(int,%20boolean))

Here is a good [article](https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-tips-tricks-implementing-splash-screen-f0f5ce046a09) to help you out